# Expected number of "BOOK"

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is a question I found online

> A monkey types at a 26-letter keyboard with one key corresponding to each of the lowercase English letters. Each keystroke is chosen independently and uniformly at random
> from the 26 possibilities. If the monkey types 1 million letters, what is the expected
> number of times the sequence “book” appears?

And this is the solution

> There are 1,000,000 − 4 + 1 = 999,997 places where “book” can appear, each with a
> (non-independent) probability of $1/26^4$ of happening. If A is the random variable that tells
> how many times “book” appears, and Ai
> is the indicator variable that is 1 if “book”
> appears starting at the ith letter, then
> $E[A] = E[A_1 +···+A_{999,997}]
> = E[A_1] +···+E[A_{999,997}]
> =
> 999,997/
> 264
> ≈ 2.19$

I don't understand why it works because i and i+1-th letter cannot be "BOOK" at the same time. How can we sum up $ E[A_{i}]$ and $E[A_{i+1}]$?

Comment: What you are focusing on is that the $999,997$ events are not independent of each other.  However, despite this, the principle of linearity of expectation still pertains.  See [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) which proves that the events do not need to be independent of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expectation is additive even if the random variables involved are not independent. If some fixed substring $s$ occurs with probability $p(s)$ in first place and probability $p(s)$ in second place, then the expected number of times that this string occurs in first or second place is $2p(s)$, even though the probability that the string appears in both places at once depends on the string in question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{E}[X+Y]=\mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$$

That is the expectation of sum is the sum of expectation. The linearity of expection does not require independence.